# How to print the Mac Command symbol in the console using python?

Tags: python, macos

I have tried printing the command symbol for mac in the terminal when running my python script, both on Windows and Linux, but it shows up as a missing character (vscode has no problem with it.)

Is there a way to fix this? or does it only show up on Mac/Mac OS? (No way of checking/don't have a mac)

I tried just pasting the symbol into the print statement eg. ⌘ and tried printing the character code for it.

```py
print("some text... CTRL + C or ⌘ + C on Mac OS)
```

```py
print("some text... CTRL + C or " + u"\u2318" + " + C on Mac OS)
```

Result for both:
[image: console output]

It is probably the console's font not handling it but I am unsure. I don't want it to look that way for everyone.

If it shows up in the Mac OS terminal, I can just check for the OS of the user and print either `CTRL + C` or `⌘ + C` so if you are on Mac OS, please answer if it does.

Comment: I hope it does not happen while doing it in python IDLE

Comment: `print("\u2318")` displays correctly for me in a MacOS Big Sur terminal window (running Python 3.8 from Homebrew but pretty vanilla other than that).

Comment: @tripleee I figured it would get captured by Mac OS, but being unsure lead me to stack. If it doesn't work, it can be changed in a revision anyway :D